# Excel VBA Tables: SumIf

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables

I have 2 tables, one is "RSO" and the other is "ESP". In the column ADD  of the table ESP a need to write a SUMIF function to sum the RESULT column if the RANGE column matches the CRITERIA column, but it is not working:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns("ADD").DataBodyRange.Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Worksheets("RSO").ListObjects(1).ListColumns("RANGE").DataBodyRange, _
Worksheets("ESP").ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Criteria").DataBodyRange, _
Worksheets("RSO").ListObjects(1).ListColumns("RESULT").DataBodyRange)
```

Could anyone tell me what is the right way to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Does all cells in column `ADD` have the same value?

Comment: No, cells in columns Range And criteria are different, so the cells in the Add column will be different

Comment: Please share smaple data and exptected result. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the formula of the worksheet cells, so you have to use the worksheet formula syntax, not the VBA syntax.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ESP").ListColumns("ADD").DataBodyRange.Formula = "=SUMIF(RSO[RANGE],[@CRITERIA],RSO[RESULT])"
```

As long as your tables are scoped to the workbook, you don't need to worry about specifying the worksheet names of the tables in the range formula.

It's probably safer to use the table name `ListObjects("ESP")` instead of the table index number `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)`, in case someone runs the macro with the wrong sheet active.